# How can I regain answering privilege after being answer-banned?

Tags: support

My account is restricted from answering questions, but I want to post. How can I do this? Should I create a new account? Why wasn't I notified via e-mail? Why not just let the moderator delete a poor answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** create a new account. According to MSE guidance at the question [*'What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?'*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th):

> **Can I simply create a new account?**
> No. The automatic ban is at [a lower level than account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error/76167#comment174425_72205). If you do end up creating a new account, it will also receive the same ban.

(This is because of IP-address magic)

**So how can you get it undone?**

> ##### How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?
>
> Automatic bans never expire or "time out". This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to freely post again. **The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.**
>
> Moderators cannot lift the ban.
>
> **Before you do anything else, *fix your existing posts!*** As noted above, downvotes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled, formatted, and overly long or short? **Then fix them!**
>
> Note the emphasis on *fixing*. **Do not delete your posts.** As explained above, negative marks on deleted posts do still count towards the question ban, and the fact that they are deleted can also count against you (with the exception of questions that are 30 days or older when deleted). Deleting your posts does not help to lift the ban. Only fixing does! [You can see a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted/13203#13203) of your own deleted questions and answers.
>
> Do note that *rewriting* an existing question into a substantially different question is frowned upon. Your edits should **not** negate or invalidate existing answers. The fixed post should fundamentally be about the same issue and topic, and the existing answers should still apply to it.
>
> [...]
>
> If you really, *really* think the ban is an error, then email the team directly using the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every page. But note that reactivation of banned accounts [is not a high priority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/better-explanation-when-account-is-blocked/62374#62374).